# What is difference between ls -lh and du -sh?

Tags: files, ls, df, du

```
$ ls -lh file1.tar

-rw-r--r-- 1 wnice wnice 40K Aug  6 20:41 file1.tar

$ du -sh file1.tar

80K     file1.tar
```

Why is it showing different sizes of same file? Please help me understand

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does ls -l output a different size from ls -s?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/269480/why-does-ls-l-output-a-different-size-from-ls-s)

Comment: Duplicate is not `du` vs `ls`, but `ls` vs `ls -s`. The answer is the same.

Comment: Also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/371238/what-is-the-difference-between-file-size-in-ls-l-and-du-sh

Comment: See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/122091/difference-between-filesize-and-size-on-disk

Comment: See: https://serverfault.com/questions/290088/what-is-the-difference-between-du-h-and-ls-lh

Answer (score 7):

The `du` command shows how much disk space is *used* for the given file.

In contrast, the `ls` command shows the size of the file. The space used can be larger than the file size, depending on the filesystem used.

For example, we can create a file with the size 1 byte like this (just one newline character in the file):

```
echo > tmp.txt
```

Then check its size using `ls -l` which shows the size one byte:

```
ls -l tmp.txt 
-rw-r--r-- 1 elias elias 1 aug  6 17:50 tmp.txt
```

Then check the used space using du:

```
du -h tmp.txt 
4,0K    tmp.txt
```

So the used disk space was in this example 4 kilobytes, although the filesize is only one byte.

Comment: du is showing the block size and since the file size is smaller than the 4K block size it will only show you the 4K.  If the file was 5K in size it would now show 8K being used.  `sudo blockdev --getbsz /dev/sda1` should show the block size of the drive being used.

Comment: None of that explains why a file that is 40K in size would occupy 80K of disk space.